# Java - Field in parent class not changing

Tags: java, eclipse, class, object, inheritance

So, I have a variable in a parent class that I am trying to change in a subclass with getter/setter methods. But, the value is just staying the same and I have no idea why.. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

- Here is a breakdown of the program: In the driver class, you choose what you want to do, then it uses the current value variable and a number you choose (operand2) to get the answer. The add, subtract, multiply and divide are in the memory calculator class. It can also clear, which sets the current value variable to zero. Now, we are adding a sub class to it that does exponents and logarithms.
- specifics: The variable currentValue in the MemoryCalc class stays the same when I try to use the power or log methods in the ScientificMemCalc class. In that class it uses a getter method to get the current value and then attempts to use a setter method to change the current value. But nothing changes. And another problem: the getter method gets a zero value from the currentValue field.

Here is driver class with main method:

```
package ScientificMemCalc;

import java.util.Scanner;

import ScientificMemCalc.MemoryCalc;

public class ScientificCalcDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    MemoryCalc calculator = new MemoryCalc();
    ScientificMemCalc scientificCalc = new ScientificMemCalc();


    int menu = 0;
    double operand2, answer;

    while (menu !=8) {

        answer = calculator.getCurrentValue();
        System.out.println("The current value is: " + answer);  

        menu = getMenuOption();

        switch(menu) {
        case 1:
            // Add
            operand2 = calculator.getOperand("What is the second number?: ");
            calculator.add(operand2);
            break;

        case 2:
            // Subtract
            operand2 = calculator.getOperand("What is the second number?: ");
            calculator.subtract(operand2);
            break;

        case 3:
            // Multiply
            operand2 = calculator.getOperand("What is the second number?: ");
            calculator.multiply(operand2);
            break;

        case 4:
            // Divide
            operand2 = calculator.getOperand("What is the second number?: ");
            calculator.divide(operand2);
            break;

        case 5:
            // Power
            operand2 = calculator.getOperand("What is the second number?: ");
            scientificCalc.power(operand2);
            break;

        case 6:
            // Logarithm
            scientificCalc.log();
            break;

        case 7:
            // Clear
            operand2 = 0;
            calculator.clear();
            break;

        case 8:
            // Quit
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static int getMenuOption() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    int choice = 0;

    // Display menu
    System.out.println("Menu:");
    System.out.println("1. Add");
    System.out.println("2. Subtract");
    System.out.println("3. Multiply");
    System.out.println("4. Divide");
    System.out.println("5. Power");
    System.out.println("6. Logarithm");
    System.out.println("7. Clear");
    System.out.println("8. Quit");

    // Get menu input
    System.out.print("What would you like to do?: ");
    choice = input.nextInt();

    while (choice < 1 || choice > 8) {
        System.out.print("Invalid. Try again: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
    }

    return choice;
    }
}
```

Here is the memory calculator class:

```
package ScientificMemCalc;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MemoryCalc {

private double currentValue;

public double getOperand(String prompt) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print(prompt);
    return input.nextDouble();

}
public double getCurrentValue() {
    return currentValue;
}
public void setCurrentValue(double temp) {
    currentValue = temp;
}
public void add(double operand2) {
    // Add
    currentValue += operand2;
}
public void subtract(double operand2) {
    // Subtract
    currentValue -= operand2;
}
public void multiply(double operand2) {
    // Multiply
    currentValue *= operand2;
}
public void divide(double operand2) {
    // Divide
    if (operand2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("You cannot divide by zero!");
        currentValue = Double.NaN;
    }
    else {
        currentValue /= operand2;
    }
}
public void clear() {
    // Clear
    currentValue = 0;

    }
}
```

And finally the subclass to add scientific functions:

```
package ScientificMemCalc;

public class ScientificMemCalc extends MemoryCalc {

public void power(double operand2) {
    // Power
    double currentValue = getCurrentValue();
    double temp = Math.pow(currentValue, operand2);
    setCurrentValue(temp);
}
public void log() {
    // Logarithm
    double currentValue = getCurrentValue();
    double temp = Math.log(currentValue);
    setCurrentValue(temp);
    }

}
```

Comment: There are multiple objects, each with their *own* `currentValue` instance field. Inheritance is *discrete* from instances: `calculator`, one object, `scientificCalc`, another object with *its own* fields. Changes to one object will not directly affect the other, regardless of inheritance. (`static` fields are another topic; they are also not inherited, but have curious access behavior in Java..)

Comment: One way to approach this problem might be to have a `CalculatorState` class which would, for example, contain the `currentValue` and access to such. Then: `s = new CalculatorState(); c1 = new Calculator(s); c2 = new SuperCoolCalculator(s);`. Now both calculator instances *share* a common state instance ("s") that they can modify.

Comment: The context/error in the last comment is not clear to me :} What 'says' "undefined"?

Comment: Thanks for the help! That makes sense why its value stays the same then. Could there be a fix without adding another class? Its for an assignment and we can only have those... What I was originally doing, was for example "calculator.power(operand2);" but then it says that the power method is undefined for the calculator object. Now I know whats going on, a better question would be: Can I access the subclass power and log methods through the calculator object? @user2864740

Comment: In this particular case you can use `scientificCalc` object for all the calculations. `ScientificMemCalc` extends `MemoryCalc` so it inherits the parent's methods.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful, now I understand

Comment: @Zach, did the answer help you? If yes, pls upvote to let other users know.

Answer (score 0):

In the ScientificMemCalc class you extend MemoryCalc, this lets ScientificMemCalc call the methods created in MemoryCalc and provides access to its own set of variables in MemoryCalc. However, when creating two separate objects of each class, they will both have access to a variable of the same name and type, but they will be two separate variables in two separate objects.

One solution is passing in a MemoryCalc object into the constructor of the ScientificMemCalc class then calling the getCurrentValue()/setCurrentValue() methods in respects to that object. Allowing access to the same variable.

```
package scientificMemCalc;

public class ScientificMemCalc {

    //store the MemoryCalc object so we have access to the needed data
    private MemoryCalc memCalc;

    //store the MemoryCalc
    public ScientificMemCalc(MemoryCalc memCalc) {
        this.memCalc = memCalc;
    }

    public void power(double operand2) {

        // Power
        double currentValue = memCalc.getCurrentValue();
        double temp = Math.pow(currentValue, operand2);
        memCalc.setCurrentValue(temp);

    }

    public void log() {

        // Logarithm
        double currentValue = memCalc.getCurrentValue();
        double temp = Math.log(currentValue);
        memCalc.setCurrentValue(temp);

    }

}
```

Then when instantiating your ScientificMemCalc object pass in the reference for your MemoryCalc.

```
MemoryCalc calculator = new MemoryCalc();
ScientificMemCalc scientificCalc = new ScientificMemCalc(calculator);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You bet! Happy to help!

Comment: name of the packages should always be lowercase

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

You're interacting with TWO DIFFERENT OBJECTS `calculator` and `scientificCalc`. They do not share any state.

**What can you do?**

1. Use `scientificCalc` for all the calculations. Thus the value will be one and only.

*cons* : the things can become much more complicated once you introduce another calculator types

2. Pass the `calculator` to constructor of `ScientificMemCalc` as a constuctor parameter.

*cons* : same as for #1

3. Use a separate class/object for storing the state. (as suggested by @user2864740)
4. Do not store the state inside the calculator (Why would you need that?). Pass all the operands (current state will be always operand #1) to the methods and return the result to caller:

   ```
   int menu = 0;
   double operand2, answer;
   while (menu !=8) {

       // You don't need this line
       //answer = calculator.getCurrentValue();

       System.out.println("The current value is: " + answer);  

       menu = getMenuOption();

       switch(menu) {
       case 1:
           // Add
           operand2 = calculator.getOperand("What is the second number?: ");
           // 
           answer = calculator.add(answer, operand2);
           break;
           //... modify other operations in the same way
   }
   ```